# Why my model is transparent, but X-Ray is disabled?

Tags: modeling

I have used addon SpeedRetopo to create this mesh, but when I exited from addon interface and returned in blender interface I saw this:
[image: transperent model]

Answer (score 0):

check your face orientation, the normals might be flipped !